# onEdit(e) trigger does nothing when cell is being edited

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to change the text in a cell (different from the edited one) when a specific cell is being edited

I am using the following code:

```
function get_cells(){
  
  if (sheet.getRange(3,6).getValue() == 'Cat') {
  sheet.getRange(5,5).setValue('Animal')
} else if (sheet.getRange(3,6).getValue() == 'Apple') {
  sheet.getRange(5,5).setValue('Fruit')
} else {
  sheet.getRange(5,5).setValue(NaN)
}

}

function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range;

  if (range.getRow()== 3 && range.getColumn()==6){
    get_cells();
  }
}
```

The idea is that when the cell (3,6) is edited then the content of the cell (5,5) will be changed automatically. But it doesn't work

Comment: Do you mean to use `getRow()` and `getColumn()`?

Comment: sorry, that was a typing mistake, it still doesn't have the intended behaviour (nothing happens :()

Comment: Where are you defining `sheet` used in `get_cells`?

Comment: omg, thank you, I thought I defined it globally but I was wrong. It works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

Get cells required the sheet.  You could have learned this by viewing you executions.

```
function get_cells(sheet) {

  if (sheet.getRange(3, 6).getValue() == 'Cat') {
    sheet.getRange(5, 5).setValue('Animal')
  } else if (sheet.getRange(3, 6).getValue() == 'Apple') {
    sheet.getRange(5, 5).setValue('Fruit')
  } else {
    sheet.getRange(5, 5).setValue(NaN)
  }

}

function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('entry');
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.rowStart == 3 && e.range.columnStart == 6) {
    e.source.toast('first if')
    get_cells(sheet);
  }
}
```

[Incomplete list of event object values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events?hl=en#edit)